# How to prove the following relation for the conditional entropy

Tags: information-theory, entropy

I want to prove Eq 2.21 of "Elements of information theory" which is given as follows $$H(X,Y\mid Z)=H(X\mid Z)+H(Y\mid X,Z)$$ Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The book states that it is similar to the proof of $H(X,Y) = H(X) + H(Y \mid X)$. Indeed just take that proof and replace $p(x,y)$ with $p(x,y \mid z)$, replace $p(x)$ with $p(x \mid z)$, and replace $p(y \mid x)$ with $p(y \mid x,z)$.

Comment: @angryavian thank you for your prompt help. Then I think it is also equal to $H(Y|Z)+H(X|Y,Z)$ (I am assuming that $p(x,y|z)=p(x|y,z)p(y|z)$)? Is it also right?